# Problems with testing a post action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing tests for my rails app. I have a comments model that belongs to two different models. The code is given below.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

has_ancestry 
  # each comment is created by a user
  belongs_to :user
  # each comment is attached to a scoreboard
  belongs_to :scoreboard
```

The comments controller is given below.

```
def new
 @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
 @comment = @scoreboard.comments.new  :parent_id => params[:parent_id]
end

def create
 @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
 @comment = @scoreboard.comments.new comment_params
 respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to scoreboard_url(@comment.scoreboard_id) }
  else
   format.html { 
    redirect_to scoreboard_url(@comment.scoreboard_id)
    flash[:danger] = 'Comment cannot be blank and must be less than 140 characters'
   }
  end
 end
end
```

The comment params

private

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :parent_id).merge(user_id: current_user.id) #the merge function allows each comment ot be associated with the user
 end
```

The comment fixture file and the integration_test code is given below.

```
comment_a:
   body: myprecious
   user: divjot
   scoreboard: scoreboard_b

class CommentsCreateTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup 
    @scoreboard = scoreboards(:scoreboard_b)
    @user = users(:divjot)
    @comment = comments(:comment_a)
  end

  test "successfull creation of the comment" do
xhr :post, scoreboard_comments_path(:id => @scorebaord.id), comment: {body: "abc"}       
end
```

The test above gives me the following error.

```
 1) Error:
CommentsCreateTest#test_successfull_creation_of_the_comment:
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
    test/integration/comments_create_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:CommentsCreateTest>'
```

Scoreboards.yml

```
scoreboard_a:
  name_of_scoreboard: MyString
  name_of_organization: MyString
  name_of_activity: MyStrings
  states: Ontario
  country: Canada
  cities: Guelph
  created_at: <%= 10.minutes.ago %>
  user: divjot
scoreboard_b:

name_of_scoreboard: MyString
  name_of_organization: MyString
  name_of_activity: MyStrings
  states: Ontario
  country: Canada
  cities: Guelph
  created_at: <%= 10.minutes.ago %>
```

I am not sure why I get this error. The class @scoreboard is defined both in the controllers and the setup. I wanted to test the behavior which associates each comment with a scoreboard and a user. I merge the user_id in the comment params to make sure that each comment is associated with the current user. I am not sure how to write the tests that reflect that behavior. I could pass in the user parameter but I am not exactly sure. Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: How does the fixture file for scoreboards look like? Looks like `scoreboards(:scoreboard_b)` is returning `nil` which is assigned to `@scoreboard` and you calling `id` on `@scoreboard` if throwing the error.

Comment: @Dharm, I'll edit my original question with the scoreboard fixture file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in your test. `@scorebaord.id` should be `@scoreboard.id`.

Comment: @jijohnstone, I needed to pass in the scoreboard_id, so the code I used was  'xhr :post, scoreboard_comments_path(:scoreboard_id => @scoreboard.id), comment: {body: "abc"}'. I still get the same error as before. Undefined method ID for nil class.

Comment: You're getting that error because `@scoreboard.id` is misspelled in line 11 of `test/integration/comments_create_test.rb`. You have the "o" and the "a" transposed.